# How can I download an older version "minecraft_server.jar" for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am a YouTuber and I'm thinking of making a modded series with my friend. I went to the Minecraft website to download v1.6.4 of the server, but they don't have it. So I then searched via Google and found McNostalgia and MVC (Minecraft Version Changer) but it only had v1.6.2 and below.

How can I obtain the Minecraft server jar for an older version?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting a link for a specific version of Minecraft. We are not an asset location service.

Comment: Do you have a meta link for that?

Comment: I truly do not see how "I need to install an old version of the Minecraft client" is an allowed question, but "I need to install an old version of the Minecraft server" is not.  Let's look past the words used to see the problem the asker has.

Answer (score 12):

An extensive list of download links to older minecraft.jars and minecraft_server.jars can be found on https://mcversions.net/.

The links provided on that site are the same as the download links provided in Mojang's update posts, like [this one](https://mojang.com/2014/04/minecraft-1-7-6/), and hosted by Mojang themselves (Rehosting would violate Mojang's TOS).

In their own words:

> [MCVersions.net] is a small project designed to make obtaining versions of Minecraft easy and simple. All content is provided by Mojang and is never re-distributed. [...] this website [is] not affiliated with Mojang AB.

Answer (score 5):

You can download [v.1.6.4 of “minecraft_server.jar” here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.6.4/minecraft_server.1.6.4.jar):
https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.6.4/minecraft_server.1.6.4.jar

Comment: @MBraedley fixed it